# How to print specific number right of the decimal point

Tags: python

```
1.45
4
```

Hey everyone i need to print number right of the decimal point like if i input 1.45 it needs to output 4 because its first number after point i also tried multiplying by 10 or 100 but i dont know much numbers will be after point so if there is 3 numbers after point youn still need to print the first number after point. I have tried using  ".2f" which didnt work it just made things worse i also tried finding things in internet all i found was about ".2f".

Comment: I'm not sure how easy this is. Floating point numbers can't exactly represent all decimal numbers.

Comment: Your concern is with the string representation of the number   not its value. Try this: `str(myfloat).partition(".")[2][0]`. In the real world you would need to add some validation or error trapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just multiply by 10, ignore any fractional component by converting to int then print the value modulus 10. Like this:

```
n = 1.45

print(int(n * 10) % 10)
```

**Output:**

```
4
```

Comment: Thx i dont know how i didnt think of that it fixed my problem

Comment: @TurtleSam If an answer solves your problem or is helpful, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check-mark next to the post or upvoting it by clicking the up arrow! This is completely optional!

Answer (score 0):

Use `format` with a floating-point format specifier to convert a number to a string:

```
x = 1.45
'{:f}'.format(x) # '1.45'
```

(the format specifier is needed to avoid using scientific notation like
`1e-09`)

Use `split` to find the fractional part:

```
x = 99
'{:f}'.format(x).split('.') # ['99', '000000']
```

Take the second part from the list:

```
x = -3.1415
'{:f}'.format(x).split('.')[1] # '141500'
```

Then take the first character:

```
x = 1.45
print('{:f}'.format(x).split('.')[1][0]) # 4
```

---

With a slight modification, this will work to extract any decimal digit:

```
x = 0.000000000001234
print('{:20f}'.format(x).split('.')[1][12]) # 12th decimal is 2
```

Here, I used `20` to generate enough decimals (default is 6).